# Show name generated in app without connecting to wifi to other device in android like xender , shareit

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

How does [Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender&hl=en) , [Shareit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps&hl=en) etc display name of device without connecting to other device wifi.

Can i use the same technique for bluetooth i.e. display user name of all devices that run my app without pairing to device(s).

This question is not related to how to connect to `wifi` or `wifi-direct`

Answer (score 0):

When you start receiving file in shareit or xender the wifi hotspot of receiver starts which bring both devices in same network.

Comment: But before sending files user can see list of user(s) that use xender or shareit. And when they select any one then file transfer start.

Comment: yes.. coz before connecting to wifi u can see all the active hotspots

Comment: But xender and shareit create some random hotspot name